# Bind property from View to ViewModel

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a property `MyFunc` in my custom view:

```
public class MyView : MvxLinearLayout
{
    public Func<Task<byte[]>> MyFunc { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to call this function from the ViewModel. How can I bind to it so I can have it in my ViewModel?

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public Func<Task<byte[]>> MyFunc { get; set; } // Bind to it here so I can call it within this class
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bindings work the other way around.

Source is always ViewModel
Target is always View

I don't know what you want to achieve with this. However, it looks like you want to populate your LinearLayout with images or some kind of byte data.

For that, use a Command. If you really want a platform specific function to trigger in your shared code, you can use MvxInteraction.

Comment: A platform specific function is what I want. I'll take a look at MvxInteraction

Comment: It's platform specific code that does things like UI animations, record audio, etc.